# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'background' of object '#<Object>'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

my project is babel7.

```
render() {
  const {elementStyle, style } = this.props;
  return (
            <span style={Object.assign(elementStyle, style)}>{label} 
            </span>
        )
}
```

//Object.assign(elementStyle, style) --> error.
but i correct Object.assign({}, elementStyle, style)  is working.
and why is not working?? 
 i debuggered this code. at first is working but when reredering, this code is error...
i don't know please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of `Object.assign` is the target that the other arguments will get merged into, but that first argument gets *mutated* and returned by the function.

> The Object.assign() method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It will return the target object.

`elementStyle` seems to be read only, so it cannot be mutated. As you mentioned, passing an empty object fixes the error since it is mutating the newly created empty object, and merging `elementStyle` and `style` with it, while leaving both `elementStyle` and `style` as they are.

Hope this helps to clarify. You can read more about [Object.assign on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).